# Plot of Galerkin method issue

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Please see the attached code with the attached picture which I plotted correctly using Matlab but I couldn't using Mathematica

```
Subscript[V, DC] = 2; Subscript[V, AC] = 0.3;
Subscript[W, MAX] = {};
Subscript[c, non] = 0.1;  (*C=U*)
Subscript[T, 0] = NIntegrate[ϕ[x], {x, 0, 1}]; (* Evaluating the orthogonality *)
Subscript[T, 1] = -2 NIntegrate[ϕ[x]^3, {x, 0, 1}];
Subscript[T, 2] = NIntegrate[ϕ[x]^4, {x, 0, 1}];
Subscript[T, 3] = - Subscript[α, 1] NIntegrate[ϕ[x]ϕ''[x], {x, 0, 1}]NIntegrate[ϕ'[x]^2, {x, 0, 1}];
Subscript[T, 4] = 2 Subscript[α, 1] NIntegrate[(ϕ[x]^2)ϕ''[x], {x, 0, 1}]NIntegrate[ϕ'[x]^2, {x, 0, 1}];
Subscript[T, 5] = -Subscript[α, 1] NIntegrate[(ϕ[x]^3)ϕ''[x], {x, 0, 1}]NIntegrate[ϕ'[x]^2, {x, 0, 1}];

f = (U''[t] + Subscript[ω, n]^2*U[t] + Subscript[c, non] U'[t])*(1 + U[t]*Subscript[T, 1] + U[t]^2*Subscript[T, 2]) +(U[t]^3*Subscript[T, 3] + U[t]^4*Subscript[T, 4]+U[t]^5*Subscript[T, 5]) -Subscript[α, 2]*Subscript[T, 0]*(Subscript[V, DC]+Subscript[V, AC] *Cos[Ω*t])^2 == 0; 

u0 = 0;
v0 = 0.04;
tend = 200;

Sol = Flatten[NDSolve[{f /. {Ω -> i},{U[t]}, {t, 0, tend}, MaxSteps →Infinity, Method → {"EquationSimplification"→ "Residual"}]];

maxval = NMaxValue[Evaluate[{U[t] /.3/4*tend <= t <= tend}], {t}];

AppendTo[Subscript[W, MAX] , {i, maxval}];
f[Evaluate[U[tend] /. Sol] < 0.000001,
u0 = 0.001; v0 = 0.001;,
u0 = Evaluate[u[tend] /. Sol];
v0 = Evaluate[u'[tend] /. Sol];]    ];
Subscript[graphic, 5]  = ListPlot[Subscript[W, MAX], PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Ω", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(W\), \(MAX\)]\)"}]
```

[image: The cooode and the Matlab code]

Comment: Did you fix all these error you get from Mathematica? You can't call `NIntegrate` on integrand that contains symbols with no values. Check all the calls to `Nintegrate` in your code, and make sure you are passing them numerical values in the expression (other than ofcourse the integration variable itself).

Comment: You have several numerical integrations of `\[Phi][x]`, its powers, and its derivatives but you have not defined `\[Phi][x]`.

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite MATLAB code as it is and use `ParametricNDSolveValue[]` for parametric research, then we have

```
cnon = .1; Vdc = 2; Vac = .3; a1 = 20; a2 = 3.835; wn = 22.3733; sn = \
.982502; ϕ[x_] := 
 Cosh[Sqrt[wn] x] - Cos[Sqrt[wn] x] - 
  sn (Sinh[Sqrt[wn] x] - Sin[Sqrt[wn] x]);
(*C=U*)T0 = 
 NIntegrate[ϕ[x], {x, 0, 
   1}];(*Evaluating the orthogonality*)T1 = -2 NIntegrate[ϕ[
     x]^3, {x, 0, 1}];
T2 = NIntegrate[ϕ[x]^4, {x, 0, 1}];
T3 = -a1 NIntegrate[ϕ[x] ϕ''[x], {x, 0, 
     1}] NIntegrate[ϕ'[x]^2, {x, 0, 1}];
T4 = 2 a1 NIntegrate[(ϕ[x]^2) ϕ''[x], {x, 0, 
     1}] NIntegrate[ϕ'[x]^2, {x, 0, 1}];
T5 = -a1 NIntegrate[(ϕ[x]^3) ϕ''[x], {x, 0, 
     1}] NIntegrate[ϕ'[x]^2, {x, 0, 1}];

f = (U''[t] + wn^2*U[t] + cnon U'[t])*(1 + U[t]*T1 + 
       U[t]^2*T2) + (U[t]^3*T3 + U[t]^4*T4 + U[t]^5*T5) - 
    a2*T0*(Vdc + Vac*Cos[om*t])^2 == 0;

u0 = 0;
v0 = 0.04;
tend = 20;

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(U''[t] + wn^2*U[t] + cnon U'[t])*(1 + 
         U[t]*T1 + U[t]^2*T2) + (U[t]^3*T3 + U[t]^4*T4 + U[t]^5*T5) - 
      a2*T0*(Vdc + Vac*Cos[om*t])^2 == 0, U[0] == 0, U'[0] == 0}, 
   U, {t, 0, tend}, {om}];
```

List of maximal values of `U[t]`with different $ω $

```
lst = Table[{om, 
    Max[Table[sol[om][t], {t, 2/3 tend, tend, .01}]]}, {om, 20, 
    30, .1}];
```

Visualization of the frequency response curve and `U[t]`

```
{ListPlot[lst, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(n\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(W\), \(max\)]\)"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[sol[om][t], {om, 20, 30, 5}]], {t, 2 tend/3, 
   tend}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "U[t]"}, Frame -> True,
   PlotLegends -> 
   Table[Row[{"Ω = ", om}], {om, 20, 30, 5}]]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank u so much to all of u and special to u

Comment: @SSRR7755 You are welcome!

Comment: Mr. Alex What can I change for the backward sweep (Subscript[V, DC] = 4.5; Subscript[V, AC] = 0.03;) because the above is forwards sweep, where for backward sweep I change the range {om, 30, 
    20, -.1}]; with negative decement but I got no plot.. I should get something like

Comment: @SSRR7755 Is it homework? They probably made a typo with `Vac`.  Use `lst = Table[{om, 
    Max[Table[sol[om][t], {t, 2/3 tend, tend, .01}]]}, {om, 20, 
    17.5, -.05}];` for this case.

Comment: No Hw during current days bcz the spring term is over and the summer term didn't start yet but I finished all these Qs via MATLAB, and I'm trying to take advantage of my time now to over this break to learn MATHEMATICA for my future sir

Comment: @SSRR7755 It is good for you. What about  backward sweep, why it is not consistent with textbook?

Comment: I don't know but I will try to figure it out